# In Mac Safari, the second (or later) drawImage costs much more time than the first drawImage. What is the reason

Tags: canvas, safari, composition, drawimage

See the codes below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {

      const width = 1000;
      const height = 600;

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      const canvasDraft = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvasDraft.width = width;
      canvasDraft.height = height;
      const ctxDraft = canvasDraft.getContext('2d');

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

      ctxDraft.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      ctxDraft.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctxDraft.fillRect(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, width * 0.5, height * 0.5);

      console.time('the first drawImage');
      ctx.drawImage(canvasDraft, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
      console.timeEnd('the first drawImage'); // ==> 0.5ms

      ctxDraft.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      ctxDraft.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctxDraft.fillRect(0, 0, width * 0.5, height * 0.5);

      console.time('the second drawImage');
      ctx.drawImage(canvasDraft, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
      console.timeEnd('the second drawImage'); // ==> 5ms

      // comment above 3 lines and uncomment the codes below, would output 0.5ms
      // requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      //   console.time('the second drawImage');
      //   ctx.drawImage(canvasDraft, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
      //   console.timeEnd('the second drawImage');
      // });
    }, 1000);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Mac Safari, the first drawImage costs about 0.5ms, and the second costs about 5ms. (In Chrome, it costs about 0.1ms).

If I move the second drawImage to next tick, it would cost 0.5ms. Can any one explain Why? How to make the second drawImage costs less time? I really need to drawImage from one canvas to another in one tick.

Comment: Didn't took the time to even run the code yet, but beware, timing drawImage like this doesn't mean much. Nowadays browsers do try to batch GPU calls, meaning it will take almost 0s on the CPU clock, but nothing will have been moved to the GPU yet, so you may anyway have created a long frame even though the JS task was all executed in no time.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, timing drawImage does not mean much whenever it costs 0ms on the CPU clock (and nothing moved to GPU, right), but whenever drawImage costs more than 5ms on the CPU clock, it means my render-tick-in-js been blocked, and that is my case.

In chrome, it costs less than 1ms, and I don't really care about when it been actually drawn to screen (mostly very soon). In Safari, the first drawImage costs less than 1ms, just like in chrome, and the second and later drawImages costs much more. So I wonder what is the reason and is there a way to bypass the case.

Comment: yes things are moved to the GPU, that's (very probably) the thing. Modern browsers will just make the CPU batch calls to the GPU and continue with whatever comes without actually waiting for the GPU is done. However when you ask it to drawImage the first canvas, it has to wait for the GPU does its things because there is a read here. Alos, I suspect simply passing two different canvases to the GPU costs some time in this browser. But I still haven't time to look this up sorry, I'll try in the next few days to find some.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks a lot. Two different canvases is very possible to work, but my specific case is 4 different (large-size, maybe) canvases for each layer, and there's several layers, so I'm a bit worried of storage costing.

Comment: Still haven't much time, but I can confirm it's what I suspected, disabling Hardware Acceleration for canvas (`defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu -bool true` then debug > Drawing/Compositing flags > disable both Full Page Accelerated then Canvas) makes all drawings take about 0.2ms